# What's the error in this Python/Pygame code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

This is my code. I'm trying to make the sprite move around. There are classes because this is just the beginning of a project.

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
surf = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
blackorwhiteorsomething = (0, 0, 0)
surf.fill(blackorwhiteorsomething)
fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.flip()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.image = pygame.Surface((22, 22))
        self.image.fill((130, 100, 200))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x = 100, y = 300)
        self.x_vel = 0
        self.y_vel = 0
    def speed(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed
    def update(self, keys):
            if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.y_vel = 1
            elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.y_vel = -1
            else:
                self.y_vel = 0   
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.x_vel = -1
            elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.x_vel = 1
            else:
                self.x_vel = 0
    def update1(self, keys):
            if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                self.y_vel = 1
            elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
                self.y_vel = -1
            else:
                self.y_vel = 0

            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                self.x_vel = -1
            elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
                self.x_vel = 1
            else:
                self.x_vel = 0
    def draw(self, surface):
            surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

player = Player('Tank')
def main():
    while True:    
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        player.draw(surf)
        player.update(keys)
        player.update1(keys)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()

        fps_clock.tick(60)

main()
```

An error is not raised, but the sprite doesn't move. HELP!
(P.S, I'm sort of like a novice at this, so don't be too harsh if it was something stupid.)

Comment: Just ask yourself where you really update the position

Comment: In your methods `update` and `update1` you update the velocities `x_vel` and `y_vel`. But you never make an update to the actual position.

Comment: Ah, found out what it was. Silly mistake. Sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the position of the player depending on `x_vel`, `y_vel` and `speed`:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self, keys):
        self.x_vel = keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]
        self.y_vel = keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]
        self.rect.x += self.x_vel * self.speed
        self.rect.y += self.y_vel * self.speed
```